# php - redirecting from a page to another one

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I have a page with a login form in a file form.php, when I press ok it call the file post_form.php where it checks the inserted data. If data are ok, I must automatically open the file confirm.php, how I can do this?

Comment: What does happen if I call confirm.php directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function of PHP.
But be sure that there is NO output before the `header()` call or it will fail.

```
if(HERE YOUR CONDITION) {
    header("Location: confirm.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_clear(); //Make sure you've done ob_start() or not output anything to the browser    
header('Location: confirm.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

put header("Location: confirm.php"); in your if condition .